# How to access secured soap endpoint in nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication, soap

Here is a service I need to access from nodejs:
https://test.matrikkel.no/endringsloggapi_v3/endringslogg/EndringsloggWebService?WSDL

I have the username and password. 
How can I connect to service and issue requests?

Tried using 'soap' package in nodejs, but cannot understand where do I have to pass username and password.

Here is a working version done in python. Can anyone show how it works in nodejs.

```
import httplib, urllib
params = {}
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       "Accept": "text/plain",
       "Authorization": "Basic 123"}
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("test.matrikkel.no")
conn.request("GET", "/endringsloggapi_v3/endringslogg/EndringsloggWebService?WSDL", params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
# print response.status, response.reason, response.read() to verify that call went through
conn.close()
```

Best Regards,
Edijs

Comment: Have you looked into request? https://npmjs.org/package/request (look under the authentication section)

Comment: Have tried, but cannot figure it out. Getting some errors: Error: 140735076719808:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766: